# How to format a drive that has Bitlocker and a password protected BIOS?

Tags: windows-10, bios, bitlocker, gparted

I have a Dell Latitude 5400 laptop. I haven't got the BitLocker password. When I dumped https://gparted.org/ onto a USB, it turns out that's locked and the default one from https://bios-pw.org/ doesn't work.

Any help on how to format the drive at all?

Thanks.

Comment: You would need another system where the boot order could be changed.  An alternative is to boot a different drive and use a USB docking station.

Comment: I've heard you can clear a bios password by unplugging the computer, taking out the battery, popping out the CMOS battery, waiting 30 seconds, and putting it back in.

Comment: That’s extremely unlikely to work on a laptop

Comment: I can't change the boot order at all